# Question on geodesically convex set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, convex-analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a geodesic metric space (this means that every couple of points in $X$ are joined by a minimizing geodesic) and $C\subset X$ a geodesically convex set (given any couple of points in $C$ the minimizing geodesic joining them is entirely contained in $C$).

Is it true that for any point $x\in X\setminus C$ there is always a point $x'\in \partial C$ (the border of $C$) such that $d(x,c)\ge d(x',c)$ for every point $c\in C$?

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: I don't know... It seems a legit question to me

Comment: @user493456 Why did you rollback my edit? "Question on geodesically convex set" could mean litterally almoast anything. See [How to ask a good question\Choose a good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/145141).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is counterexample :

**(1) Construction of space $X$ :** Consider $B$, unit disc in
$\mathbb{R}^2$. If $C,\ D$ are isometric to $B$, then $X$ is obtained from identifying boundaries of $C,\ D$. Here
$C$ in $X$ is geodesically
convex. (That is intrinsic metric on $X$ is like a boundary surface of a coin)

**(2)** In $X$, there is $x\in X$ s.t. $x$ does not have $x'$

**Proof :** If $x$ is center of $D$, i.e. $d(x,\partial D)=1$, then assume that $x$ has $x'$

Consider a point $c_1\in C$, which is close
to $\partial C$, i.e. $$d(c_1,\partial C)=\epsilon$$

Hence $ d(x,c_1)=1+\epsilon$ so that $$d(x',c_1)\leq 1+\epsilon $$
(That is $x'$ can not escape from some hemisphere in $\partial C$.)

If $c_2\in C$ s.t. $d(c_1,c_2)=2-2\epsilon$ and a geodesic $[c_1c_2]$ contains
a center of $C$, then $ d(x,c_2)=1+\epsilon$.

So $d(x',c_2)$ is at least $d$, which is close to $\sqrt{3}$. Hence $d(x',c_2)>d(x,c_2)$. It is a contradiction.

**Explanation about** $\sqrt{3}$ : In $C\subset X$, for convenience, let $\epsilon=0$. Then
$d(c_1,c_2)=2$. Since $x'$ is around $c_1$ and $x'$ is in $\partial
C$, so $c_1c_2x'$ forms a right triangle. When $d(x',c_1)=1$,
$d(x',c_2)$ is smallest.

Comment: I do not quite follow what you are trying to do here and I have my doubts about the truthfulness of what you're saying. See, [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2514876/145141).

Comment: I did the following : In $X$, there is $x\in X$, which can not have $x'$

Comment: The construction of $X$ is not clear to me. What does $X=C\bigcup_{\partial B} D$ mean? And how can $x$ (the centre of $D$) lie outside $C$, when you say $C=D$?

Comment: $C,\ D$ are unit discs in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with Euclidean distance. Then we $attach\ them\ along\ boundaries\ of$ $C,\ D$.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise at the end of your answer ? Where does the $\sqrt{3}$ come from ?

Comment: Since $\epsilon $ is small, so $x'c_1 c_2$ is like a right triangle. I added some explanation.

Comment: Ok so when $\epsilon = 0$, it's exactly $\sqrt{3}$, therefore for some small enough $\epsilon$ (continuity) it must be $>d(x,c_2)$. That's your argument ?

Comment: Yes. For clearness, I add some again : If $a=\angle\ c_2x_2x'$ where $x_2$ is a center of $C$, then Cosine law implies 
 $$d(x',c_2)^2=1^2+(1-\epsilon)^2-2(1-\epsilon)\cos\ a $$
 $$ (1+\epsilon)^2\geq  d(x',c_1)^2 =1^2+(1-\epsilon)^2 -2(1-\epsilon )\cos\ (
 \pi-a ) $$
so that $$ d(x',c_2)^2 \geq
3-6\epsilon +\epsilon^2$$